# Automorphisms of stable curves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, curves, algebraic-curves, moduli-space

I am a bit confused by what Harris and Morrison write about the finiteness condition for stable curves in *Moduli of Curves*.

First the defintions:

> **Definition (2.12)** A stable curve is a complete connected curve that
>   has only nodes as singularities and has only finitely many automorphisms.

Directly after this he writes

> In view of the connectedness of C, its automorphism group can fail
>   to be finite only if C contains rational components.

But what about an elliptic curve $E$? This is a complete, connected, smooth curve, and it's *not* rational. But according to *Lemma IV 4.2* in Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*, given two points $P, Q \in E$, there always exists an automorphism $\sigma$ with $\sigma(P) = Q$, and $\sigma^2 = \text{id}_E$. So if $E$ has infinitely many points (e.g. $E$ is an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$), then $E$ has infinitely many automorphisms as well.

Have I overlooked something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right! A genus 1 curve has infinitely many automorphisms, and is not rational.

Of course, Harris and Morrison are aware of this, so what is going on?

**My diagnosis**: this is a case of terrible writing. I think that in the passages you quote, the authors only mean to discuss curves of genus $g \geq 2$. This is highly unclear in context, in particular given the example preceding the definition. However, if you flip forward to Chapter 4 and the discussion of the construction of $\overline{M_g}$ using GIT, you will see that the context is restricted to $g \geq 2$.

Finally, note that for curves of genus $g \geq 2$, your second quoted sentence is correct. Any component $C$ of genus 1 has to meet another component of the curve, so (up to finite index) the automorphism group acts on $C$ as a group of automorphisms fixing a point, hence a finite group.